# One job with different steps for different branches

Tags: github, jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, jobs

I am currently in a weird situation. We have one repository with multiple branches (CI and an official branch). Our current job structure has two jobs, one for each branch, for each platform we support. Our official build has different steps than our development build, all of which can be run using a script. My question is can we set up one job per platform that will look at both of the branches and run different steps according to what branch is changed? I am aware of the environment vars that get set with the github plugin. Is this something that would need to be utilized?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you figured a way to check `which branch is changed`? If yes can you please update your question with the details. Guess you are not using `Poll SCM`?

Comment: For records: you could use [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) to run a new job with parameters.